# Why is np.nan stored as string and not able to use isnull()/isna()/notnull()/notna()?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, null, series

This is the piece of code where I assigned `np.nan`:

```
df['column1'] = pd.np.where(df5.column5.str.contains("ABC"), "GHI",
               pd.np.where(df5.column5.str.contains("DEF"), "KLM", np.nan))
```

And I want to filter out rows where 'column1' is NaN. I tried using `isnull()` and `isna()` but these didn't work. What worked here is the below:

```
df = df [df['column1'] != 'nan']
```

Which means `np.nan` is stored as string. Why is this happening? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Use `None` in place of `np.nan` and then try `isnull()`. Also, avoid using `pd.np`, just use np directly, since `pd.np` is deprecated. I guess, when using `np.nan`, since the entire column is regarded as object, it works when using `!= 'nan'`

Comment: Looks like there are other strings.  `np.nan` is a float.  `np.where` uses the most common dtype - string.

Comment: Did the answer help you solve the problem? Consider accepting it, see here how-to: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/380158

Answer (score 0):

Using `np.where` will create an numpy array, in this case with strings and `np.nan`. However, running something like

```
np.array(['a', np.nan])
```

will give `array(['a', 'nan'], dtype='<U3')`. Here `np.nan` has been converted to `'nan'`.

The same happens in this case, running your code without assigning to a column with some example data like so (changed `pd.np` to `np` as commented by tidakdiinginkan):

```
np.where(df5.column5.str.contains("ABC"), "GHI", 
  np.where(df5.column5.str.contains("DEF"), "KLM", np.nan))
```

gives:

```
array(['GHI', 'GHI', 'GHI', 'GHI', 'nan', 'nan', 'KLM', 'KLM'],
      dtype='<U32')
```

What you can do instead is to use `None` instead of `np.nan`:

```
df['column1'] = pd.np.where(df5.column5.str.contains("ABC"), "GHI",
               pd.np.where(df5.column5.str.contains("DEF"), "KLM", None))
```

which will allow you to use `df['column1'].isnull()` as expected.